# How do I specify generic type parameters for a function invocation in Closure?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am working on reducing the use of accidentally-unknown generic type parameters in a code base. I am using a Closure TTL incantation like the following to coerce unknown generic types to the `undefined` type, hopefully provoking errors that let me find these cases (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50935325/1114)).

```
 * @template T
 * @template TYPE_I_ACTUALLY_USE := cond(isUnknown(T), 'undefined', T) =:
```

That has brought me to a case like this:

```javascript
/**
 * @template T
 * @template R := cond(isUnknown(T), 'undefined', T) =: 
 * @param {function():R} factory
 * @return {{prop: R}}
 */
function factoryWrapper(factory) {
  return {prop: factory()};
}

var instance = factoryWrapper(() => 2);
```

This `factoryWrapper` function takes a `factory` function that produces a value of type `R`, calls it, and wraps the result in `{prop: ...}`, for a return type of `{prop: R}`. But because I don't specify `T` or `R` when calling `factoryWrapper`, it doesn't know what type they're supposed to be, and can't tell whether the provided factory function returns the right type, so it produces an error or untyped output:

```
input0:11: WARNING - inconsistent return type
found   : number
required: undefined
var instance = factoryWrapper(() => 2);
```

In a language with a native type annotation syntax, like TypeScript, I might fix this by including the generic type parameter in the invocation:

```javascript
var instance = factoryWrapper<number>(() => 2);
```

However, I haven't been able to figure out any equivalent syntax for Closure. I took a few guesses, like the following, but none worked.

```javascript
var instance = factoryWrapper/** <number> */(() => 2);
```

How do I specify generic type parameters for a function invocation in Closure JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Closure Compiler doesn't allow you to specify type parameters when calling a generic function. But I think casting the callback will do what you want. Something like:

`var instance = factoryWrapper(/** @type {function(): number} */ (() => 2));`

Comment: +1 - also recommend [this](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types), if you haven't already read it.  The most effective approach to using closure compiler is to rigorously type things as restrictively as possible.  It's pretty good at finding errors of omission as well as commission.  In my experience, 90+% typed with no errors or warnings will yield pretty solid code (well, it does what you tell it:-).

Comment: While it's good to add type annotations, not all types are equally important. First, you want to type the things that are used across scopes: properties of classes, and variables captured in closures. Then, you want to type the formal parameters of functions. And last, you can type local variables. That's the least important one; Closure Compiler does local type inference and can infer these types in many cases. If you want more details about how JS type systems work, I gave a talk at StrangeLoop 2017. Check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuC8I1JBKv0

Comment: I agree with you - my point was it makes more sense in closure to actually try to specify your types correctly than to artificially try to create errors to find errors.  I think I type local variables maybe 3-4 times/thousand lines of code - as you say, if your interfaces, functions and parameters are well typed, closure compiler is great at sorting out the rest.  Listened to your intro, and look forward to the rest tomorrow!